# Keep adding tasks in multiprocessing pool to be read by pool

Tags: python, threadpool, python-multiprocessing, pool

One part of my application is producing a lot of tasks(essentially dictionary). Each task(dictionary) is essentially a the POST data to a third-party API.

Hence i wanted to multiprocess the execution of these tasks.

What I thought was: Create a multiprocess Pool which would read the tasks from a queue and send them to the function(FN) which would then call the API.

The issue is that: I want that I should be able to keep pushing tasks in the queue which are continuously read by the Pool. But this is not happening. On updating the queue(that is pushing tasks to queue), the function(FN) is not called. Below is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue, cpu_count, Manager


class PoolThread:
    running = False

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.initialisepool()

    @staticmethod
    def poolfunction(arg):
        print(arg)
        print(arg.qsize())
        return "processed"
        #return arg * arg

    def callb(self, a):
        print(a)

    def errcall(self, b):
        print(b)

    def initialisepool(self):
        print(cpu_count())
        self.p = Pool(cpu_count())
        self.m = Manager()
        self.q = self.m.Queue()
        self.p.map_async(self.poolfunction, (self.q,), cpu_count(), self.callb, self.errcall)

    def readcache(self):
        if not self.running:
            self.running = True
            self.threadedhandling()

    def threadedhandling(self):
        tasks = self.gettasks()
        # Push to queue
        self.q.put(tasks)


    def gettasks(self):
        dict_r = {'randomval' : 2}
        return dict_r


pt = PoolThread()
pt.readcache()
```

In the above the pool is initialized. However, on calling the readcache(), the poolfunction is not re-called. If the queue is populated with data before `self.p.map_async(self.poolfunction, (self.q,), cpu_count(), self.callb, self.errcall)` then only the poolfunction is called.

My requirement is that :

- I should keep pushing into the queue and the queue is automatically monitored to call the poolfunction.

  - how can i monitor the result of the poolfunction? The poolfunction should only get one argument at a time from the queue which is passed to the API. once the response is attained, i want to read the individual response and do further processing in a separate function. But as much as I have read about the pool, the result of the all the processes running simultaneouly is returned once every process is complete. Is this true? To handle this I am using the "chunksize" option so that even if i have 20 tasks in the queue but only 8 cores, then at a time 8 tasks are processed and their response returned. However, is it possible to keep getting response as the tasks complete?